# Proving that every natural number greater than 1 is prime or can be expressed as a product of primes, using the well-ordering principle.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I attempted to prove this fact using the well-ordering principle, here is my initial work:

Every natural number greater than 1 is either prime or can be expressed as a unique product of primes.

*Proof* Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be greater than 1, and composite.

*Existence*:  Define

$T=\{a\in\mathbb{N}: \exists b\in \mathbb{N}(ab=n) \land 1<ab<n\}$

Notice that $T$ is non-empty, since $n$ is composite. Then, by the well-ordering principle, $T$ has a smallest element: call it $\alpha$. If $\alpha$  is prime, we are done, so we assume $\alpha$  is composite.

Since $\alpha$ is composite, it can be written in terms of two integers $j,k$ such that $1<j,k<\alpha$. But then $\alpha b=jkb=j(kb)$ where $j<\alpha$. But this contradicts the fact that $\alpha$ is the smallest element of $T$. Thus $\alpha$ must be prime.

But I am stuck at this point. I proved that every natural number greater than 1 has a prime factor, but not that all its factors are prime. How can I proceed to show that its other factors must be prime as well?

Comment: You cannot prove that all factors are prime, since that is false in general. For instance, $4$ is a factor of $8$.

Comment: How should one proceed with showing that every number has a prime factorization, then? Uniqueness aside.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use the well-ordering principle to prove that every integer $n\ge2$ has a prime factor.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2776038/use-the-well-ordering-principle-to-prove-that-every-integer-n-ge2-has-a-prime)

Comment: The idea behind this inductive proof is explained at length in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3543271/242) in the linked dupe.